# How to remove duplicate html wrapper ? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation menu that needs to be wrapped with certain div and class so that CSS will apply.

**1.** The default blog post has the necessary html wrapper and css for the navigation

```
<nav class="main-navigation dd-menu toggle-menu">
     <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu-main-menu">
         <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
         <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-has-children >
             <a href="#">Books</a>
             <ul class="sub-menu">
                 <li>
                     <div class="megamenu-container container">
                         <div class="row">
                            <li>
                                <div class="megamenu-container container">
                                    <div class="row">   
                                        <li><a href="#">Rental</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">New</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Used</a></li>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>

                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </li>
             </ul>
         </li>
     </ul>
</nav>
```

**2.** The other type of blog post has a faulty navigation menu:

```
<nav class="main-navigation dd-menu toggle-menu">
     <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu-main-menu">
         <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
         <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-has-children >
             <a href="#">Books</a>
             <ul class="sub-menu">
                 <li>           
                    <li><a href="#">Rental</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">New</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Used</a></li>                       
                 </li>
             </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
</nav>
```

After executing the script below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var j = jQuery.noConflict();
        j(function() {

        j('main-navigation.dd-menu #menu-main-menu .menu-item-has-children > .sub-menu').wrapInner('<li class=""><div class="megamenu-container container"><div class="row"></div></div></li>');
        });


</script>
```

This item will now have a duplicate wrapper
**1.** The default blog post has the necessary html wrapper and css for the navigation

```
<nav class="main-navigation dd-menu toggle-menu">
     <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu-main-menu">
         <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
         <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-has-children >
             <a href="#">Books</a>
             <ul class="sub-menu">
                 <li>
                     <div class="megamenu-container container">
                         <div class="row">
                            <li>
                                <div class="megamenu-container container">
                                    <div class="row">   
                                        <li><a href="#">Rental</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">New</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Used</a></li>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>

                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </li>
             </ul>
         </li>
     </ul>
</nav>
```

How to remove the duplicate wrapper so that it will only have a single  wrapper?

Comment: Do you only have control over the script and not the html?  your script is having the new div and class added to all the first list items.  Take a look at Jquery .first() to help out.

Comment: Actually, now that I look again.. your first code sample is exactly the same as the last code sample you posted.. what is it that you're trying to get removed?  Which one is the correct goal?

Comment: Hi @Maulzal , i'm still figuring out what exception is possible. I'm trying to think if filters or if else is possible..